# Unused VBOs with shaders

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I have a mesh class with a VAO and several non-interleaved VBOs attached for things such as vertices, normals, texture coords e.t.c. The mesh is drawn with multiple shaders, where some shaders won't need all of the attached VBOs (e.g. it's shadow shader won't need normal or texture coords).

Enabling a vertex attribute for a shader that doesn't use it seems to work ok, but does it have any sort of performance impact (i.e. does OpenGL push unused data to the shader units or whatever happens in the background)? If not, what if the data is interleaved?

Comment: That's all going to be implementation-specific. Interleaved arrays won't change this.

Comment: Hmm so there is a possibility that an implementation may do just that, in which case I may create a separate VAO per mesh per render pass type with only the necessary vertex attributes enabled. If I wanted to change to interleaved attributes I wouldn't be able to do this, so I guess it's between not sending some data in all situations (if that even happens) vs the benefits of interleaved attributes?

Comment: This smells of premature optimization, which is always a bad thing. Be careful not to waste 90% of your time on something that has a 1% impact on the final performance. My best guess is that OpenGL will "push" all data when you bind the VAO, because that's essentially what you tell it to do, although I know of some cases where OpenGL will postpone data transfers untill it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: In my case it's not a big change at all (it has some small architectural decisions higher-up), and I thought that if there was a clear cut answer then I'd make that change. For now I'll leave it as it is and look in to it after when I have time to profile both ways on mobile platforms.